# Pandas: Standardize irregular time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, resampling

I'm wondering if Pandas has some built-in functionality to take random time intervals (roughly hours) and convert them to standardized hours.  Code example and non-working attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2018-09-04 01:12', '2018-09-04 02:11'], 
                   'end'  : ['2018-09-04 02:10','2018-09-04 03:20'], 
                   'val'  : [500, 600]})[['start','end','val']]

df[['start','end']] = df[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Gives us:

```
           start               end  val
2018-09-04 01:12  2018-09-04 02:10  500
2018-09-04 02:11  2018-09-04 03:20  600
```

and:

```
df = df.resample('1H', on = 'start', ).reset_index()
```

would ideally (but doesn't) yield:

```
           start               end     val
2018-09-04 01:00  2018-09-04 01:59  406.78
2018-09-04 02:00  2018-09-04 02:59  513.22
2018-09-04 03:00  2018-09-04 03:59  180.00
```

I could code some hack to make this work, but figured Pandas would have some simple function that does this.

Comment: You'll have to clarify the rationale for your desired output.  Most notably, your input does not share endpoints from one time frame to the next, but your desired output does.  It *appears* that you're making a change in the time-stamp semantics from input to output, and merely making a linear interpolation from one to the other.  Your main problem is that the method you used is for resampling a times serious, rather than the linear apportioning you seem to want.

Comment: You're right, end and start should never be the same, updated.  And you're also right in that I'm not using the right method - because I don't know the right method.  Hoping there is something that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a sufficiently common allotment to warrant its own method.  You're doing a straightforward linear apportioning of each input interval, broken at the hour.  In the first interval, you have 59 total minutes recorded, so the "value" of each minute is 500/59 (8.47+).  For the second, it's 600/50 per minute (12.0).

You can do this with a relatively simple control structure, although the individual break-down is a little "wordy".  As you create the new rows, use the `shift` operator to address both the current and previous rows of the input data frame.  You need to keep track of the breakpoint (top of the hour) for each row and do that linear computation for both.  Your arithmetic looks something like

```
TIME          VALUE
1:00 - 2:00   (1:12 - 1:00) * 0 + (2:00 - 1:12) * 500/59
2:00 - 3:00   (2:11 - 2:00) * 500/59 + (3:00 - 2:11) * 600/50
3:00 - 4:00   (3:20 - 3:00) * 600/50 + (4:00 - 3:20) * 0
```

Can you turn those details into the code you need?

Comment: I appreciate the effort and while what you're suggesting would get me there, I was hoping pandas offered something more elegant.  If that's not the case, It'll have to make do.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no existing function to do this succinctly.  Linear-interpolate-and-recombine isn't built in.  You could get some good karma by pushing such functionality to open source.  :-)

Comment: I'm afraid that's above my pay-grade, but I'll see what I can hack together and post it here.  Thanks for your help.